# Rails: Validating that start is before stop, DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am trying to use [`validates_timeliness`](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness) to ensure that `SliderImage.start` is always before `SliderImage.stop`:

```
class SliderImage < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_datetime :start, :stop
  validates :start, :timeliness => {:before => stop}

end
```

But of course `stop` is not defined yet.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stop value must be called on the record object being evaluated. The shorthand version is pass the symbol :stop, and this be assumed to be method on the record which will called at validation time.

Otherwise you can use a lambda like so

```
lambda {|r| r.stop }
```

I would tend to write your validation as

```
validates_datetime :start
validates_datetime :stop, :after => :start
```

p.s. I'm the plugin author :)

Answer (score 5):

A simpler way to use this validation without installing any gem is calling a method to validate:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :start_date_before_end_date

  def start_date_before_end_date
    if self.start_date > self.end_date
      errors.add(:start_date, "Start date should be before end date")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: As an aside, if you are going to use this validator in multiple places, consider making it a global validator. Followed this article with great success. http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-validators-in-ruby-on-rails-4